# Adding Activate/Deactivate button in MVC jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I have FormTemplate class in my project

```
public class FormTemplate : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DateCreation { get; set; }
    public virtual FormTemplateGroup Group { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual FormTemplateStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<QuestionBlock> QuestionBlocks { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsFreeze { get; set; }
}
```

and I use MVC jqGrid http://mvcjqgrid.skaele.it/Home/Formatters
to show the list of FormTemplates on the page

```
@(Html.Grid("Grid")
            .SetCaption("List")
            .AddColumn(new Column("Name").SetLabel("Name"))
            .AddColumn(new Column("GroupFor").SetLabel("Group"))
            .AddColumn(new Column("DateCreation").SetLabel("Date"))
            .AddColumn(new Column("Status").SetLabel("Status")).SetSortOnHeaderClick(false)
            .AddColumn(new Column("Id").SetLabel("&nbsp;").SetCustomFormatter("buttonize").SetWidth(220).SetAlign(Align.Center))
            .SetAutoWidth(false)
            .SetRowNumbers(true)
            .SetUrl(Url.Action("FormTemplateGridData"))
            .SetAutoWidth(true)
            .SetRowNum(10)
            .SetRowList(new[] { 5, 10, 15, 20 })
            .SetViewRecords(true)
            .SetPager("Pager"))
```

I don't show value of `IsFreeze` property on my page, but I need to add Activate button if `IsFreeze == true` and Deactivate button otherwise for every FormTemplate.

I tried to add the checking function in `buttonize`

```
function buttonize(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
        var result = '<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">' + '&nbsp;'
            + '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">' + '&nbsp;';

        if (isFreezeTemplate(rowobject[4])) {
            result += '<input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="activateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">';
        }
        else {
            result += '<input type="button" value="Deativate" onclick="deactivateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">';
        }
        return result;
    }
```

added function

```
function isFreezeTemplate(id) {
        var check = $.post('@Url.Action("IsFreezeFormTemplate")', { id: id });
        return check;
    }
```

and added in controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool IsFreezeFormTemplate(int id)
    {
        var formTemplate =
            FormTemplateRepository.Query()
            .Where(ft => ft.Id == id)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (formTemplate.IsFreeze == true) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

but I get only Activate buttons for all FormTemplates on my page.
How to fix it?

Comment: Did you know that [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is an asynchronous object which returns a `jqXHR` object but not the returned value from your action? You should have a property that you send to your code instead...

Comment: Can you explain me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a hidden column to the grid from which you read the value in your buttonize function through the rowobject argument.

```
.AddColumn(new Column("IsFreeze").SetHidden(true))
```

This way you don't need the ajax request.

Comment: Come to think of it, you probably don't even need the column. If the IsFreeze field is included in the data coming from the server, it is probably also in the rowobject argument.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to fill the `IsFreeze` in the `FormTemplateGridData` action (if not done) and to use it directly in your `buttonize` function :

```
function buttonize(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
    var result = '<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">' + '&nbsp;'
        + '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">' + '&nbsp;';

    if (rowobject["IsFreeze"]) {
        result += '<input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="activateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">';
    }
    else {
        result += '<input type="button" value="Deactivate" onclick="deactivateTemplate(' + options.rowId + ')">';
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

**Edit - action code**

In order to precise what is being send to the grid, here is the code of the grid data action :

```
public JsonResult FormTemplateGridData()
{
    var donnees = new
    {
        total = 2,
        page = 1,
        records = 2,
        rows = new List<FormTemplate>
        {
            new FormTemplate { Id = 1, Active = true, Name = "first", IsFreeze = true },
            new FormTemplate { Id = 2, Active = true, Name = "second", IsFreeze = true  },
            new FormTemplate { Id = 3, Active = false, Name = "last", IsFreeze = false  }
        }
    };

    return Json(donnees);
}
```

Comment: I added `.AddColumn(new Column("IsFreeze").SetHidden(true))` in my grid but in `buttonuze`-function `if (rowobject["IsFreeze"])` doesn't work. I checked in console, `rowobject` is Array and it contains, for example, `rowobject: Array[6]
0: "Template1"
1: "Group 2"
2: "10.10.2010 0:00:00"
3: "New"
4: "False"
5: "1"` but I dont understand how to get the 4th value from this array. I tried `rowobject[4]`, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: if(rowobject[4] == "True"

Comment: @Robin van der Knaap thanks a lot, I already have found this way.

Comment: @Heidel so does one of the solution work now? But for the rowobject, it depends on your json object returned by your `FormTemplateGridData` action. For my part, `rows` was a list of `FormTemplate`, thus the different fields can be accessed directly and as JSON so if the type is boolean, I get a JS bool (that's why my test is `rowobject["IsFreeze"]`...